Is there a way to track whole frame call stack in Tracy whitout calling ZoneScoped in every function?
I'm using Tracy (https://github.com/wolfpld/tracy) and i want to track every function call in frame, but adding ZoneScoped to each of them is pretty much impossible, so can i somehow instrument Tracy to track everything in frame?

run your executable with higher privileges and tracy should run with sampling profiling

@Raildex That was it, can you post this as answer so i can mark as resolved?

Tracy needs higher privileges to use the sampling profiler.
Run your client with admin rights on Windows or superuser privileges on linux and unix.
